# Has anyone ever successfully compiled Vowpal Wabbit on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin, mingw, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to compile Vowpal Wabbit on a Windows 7 machine and after trying Netbeans, Cygwin, and MinGW I'm starting to wonder if I'm trying something that's even feasible.

Each of the above has required ****.h files that aren't designed for windows such as sys/socket.h.

Anyone that has actually done this, I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Langford recently made a post to the VW mailing list saying a Windows port was in progress, but still broken in certain respects.  I would suspect that it currently is not possible to get VW running on windows (but I haven't actually tried)

[From this thread:](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vowpal_wabbit/message/1029)

> Chris Quirk created a windows port for VW, which is now in the
>   distribution. It's still incomplete: networking and threads are
>   problem points.

Answer (score 6):

- Run cygwin's setup.exe, type "boost", click on "Default" several times until it changes to "Install", proceed with installing boost library from cygwin.
- Download latest Vowpal Wabbit and extract to you vw directory.
- Open cygwin and go to that vw directory, where Makefile is(cd .. (see @home)  cd vw_dir)
- In cygwin command prompt type "make"

After that you can close cygwin, and use cmd to run vowpal.

Comment: I also had to install 'libtool' and 'make', for some reason they were not included by default

Comment: How to run vowpal when I build it? just run vw.exe? (but it requires cygwin1.dll)

Answer (score 2):

I took this from a kaggle forum:
"
I managed to compile VW under Windows 7 64 bit without Professional Visual Studio 2010.

You can do it by using Cygwin ( http://www.cygwin.com/ ).

1. first of all install Cygwin on your computer: just choose the standard configuration
2. run Cygwin shell and enter : git clone git://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit.git
3. after the download have completed write: cd vowpal_wabbit
4. at this point you can run the command: configure
5. the configure procedure will point out all the libraries which are missing from your system and that you should install by running again the Cygwin setup
6. after some iterations of point 5 you will have finally provided all the necessary libraries to Cygwin, and you can run the command: make

7 after the compiler will finish the make of vw.exe, run: make test in order to check if everything is all right with your build.

Now you can start using VW under Windows, just open a shell and try it.
"

Comment: For me, the command "configure" (step 4) didn't work.  I typed dir and notice there was a file named autogen.sh.  I don't know what this is but I typed ./autogen.sh anyway and stuff started happening.  I read the text as it scrolled down the screen and I notice it said it had created vowpal_wabbit/make - and I had been previously trying to use the make command to do the install (but it wasn't working).

So, after the autogen.sh stopped running I just typed "make" - and it worked! Now a bunch of stuff is happening... I'll write back later if this stuff isn't good stuff...

Comment: @Phillio - I followed your instructions above and it works fine for me. Many thanks. Ps: I too had the same issue at step-4 but following your comment above helped me a great deal.

Comment: "write cd vowpal_wabbit" in cygwin?

Answer (score 2):

Another update, binary releases for Windows is now available since 21 June 2016. The latest link as of today is: https://github.com/eisber/vowpal_wabbit/releases/tag/v8.2.0.6

It's available in MSI installer file.

(In case you encounter dead link in the future, please find most recent version from the eisber's github repo.)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to build on 64bit win without cygwin,  native windows.  Took a long time to set up env for the build so I wrote a blog about it.  I know that self promotion is frowned upon but [this link has the binary I built](http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/post/2014/11/13/vowpal-wabbit-for-windows-and-binary-for-win-x64/) on my machine, guaranteed to work on only my machine but anyone is free to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

An update for curious googlers: the VW Windows instructions have recently been updated, and if you get the most recent source you should be able to compile on Visual Studio without major hurdles (I have tried successfully): https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/README.windows.txt